# Session.GetObject in Tridion 2011 returns component for non-existing item

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a component is null (e.g. not found in Tridion) in a custom backend. I just don't see how to check this, other than catching the error.

```
Component comp = (Component)session.GetObject(base.ComponentUri);

if (component != null)
{
    bool isCheckedOut = component.IsCheckedOut;
}
else
{
    // how do I get in here!
}
```

I'm 100% sure the uri is correct ('tcm:113-438134') and 100% sure that there's no item in Tridion with that URI. 
The code above will throw an error at component.IsCheckedOut:

```
The item tcm:113-438134-16 does not exist.
```

How do I check the existence of a Tridion item? 
I've tried placing the cast at the end, which didn't help much:

```
Component comp = session.GetObject(base.ComponentUri) as Component;
```

and I've tried not casting at all but using an IdentifiableObject, which also didn't make any difference.
Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because of Tridion's lazy loading - It will never return a null object if the URI seems valid. You can use `session.IsExistingObject(TcmUriOrWebdavUrl)` to check if the object exists.

And...

I'm sure you're expecting this...

> in a custom backend

You cannot use the TOM.NET API for processes other than Templates and Event System. Please use the Core Service API instead.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't quite expecting that **;)**. Is that because TOM.NET is still 'read-only'?

Comment: No, it's because loading the TOM.NET actually loads a lot more than just an interface into Tridion - it loads Tridion in your process. The whole of it. With its event loaders, and queue management, and database connection pooling, and multi-threading, and COM instances, and templating Engines, etc. Official blurb here: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_19AF6C2427DF4781A866981FA8D62192

Comment: No, you can't use because we don't support it :) and it may stop working or do _weird things_ to your environment